# r plotly error_y weird results with grouped values

Tags: r, plotly

I've got some problems plotting an std deviation of some value Y grouped by a factor G, here's the df

```
df<-data.frame("X"=c(1:20),"Y"=c(1:20),"SD"=c(1:20),"G"=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",5),rep("C",4),rep("D",5),rep("A",3)))
```

If I plot the value and the sd without grouping them everything is OK:

```
p3<-plot_ly(df,
x=~X,
y=~Y,
#color=~G
type="scatter",
mode="markers",
marker=list(symbol="x"),

error_y =list(
    array=~SD,
    thickness=1
    )
)
p3
```

This yields the following plot:

[image]

But when i try to plot Y+SD grouped by G the SD appears not in the correct order. See the resulting plot below:

```
p3<-plot_ly(df,
    x=~X,
    y=~Y,
    color=~G,
    type="scatter",
    mode="markers",
    marker=list(symbol="x"),
    error_y =list(array=~SD,
                  thickness=1
    )
)
p3
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Perhaps file a ticket with the Plotly developers?

Comment: @Maximilian Peters how can i contact Plotly developers

Comment: https://github.com/plotly, file a ticket there.

Comment: Ticket opened (I hope) https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1110